# Dynamic package installation depend upon the specific system using setup.py install_requires

Tags: python, setup.py, install-requires

I have a setup.py as below configuration

```
setup(
install_requires = ['django == 2.0']
)
```

I would like to modify the setup.py based on docker usage.

If user uses docker then the configuration must be

```
setup(
install_requires = ['django == 4.0']
)
```

else

```
setup(
install_requires = ['django == 2.0']
)
```

I have tried using environement variable but not working.

```
if 'ENV_VAR' in os.environ:
  django = ['django == 4.0']
else:
 django = ['django == 2.0']

setup(
install_requires = django
)
```

Comment: may be you should use environment markers

Comment: @DPS, I tried that too but not able to differentiate between docker and other platforms.